# Can't solve the problem of dlib error on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04

Tags: python, cmake, face-recognition, dlib

Now I have spent 3 days working on this dlib to install it but it ends with error.
I am installing dlib on server with virtual environment and what I tried so far are:

1. Install dlib from `requirements.txt` with error cmake.
2. Install cmake first and then checked the version of cmake it was 3.20.0
3. Upload dlib 19.2 on server, extract it and then `setup.py install` (same thing it reached 84 and stop for ages).
4. Install setup.py without graphics and get the same.
5. Change Linux image to CentOS and also Debian and try (get same thing).
6. I install `labboost-all-dev` with 'scikit' and all but get same.

anyway i tried what i can do but if you have something to add plase help

The error in general like this after completing 70%:

```
[ 70%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/src/dlib.cpp.o
      In file included from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:16,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/attr.h:13,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:43,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/../dlib/python/pybind_utils.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/../dlib/python.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/tools/python/src/opaque_types.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/tools/python/src/dlib.cpp:4:
      /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/internals.h: In function ‘pybind11::detail::internals& pybind11::detail::get_internals()’:
      /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/internals.h:194:27: warning: ‘void PyEval_InitThreads()’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        194 |         PyEval_InitThreads();
            |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:130,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:112,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pytypes.h:12,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:13,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/attr.h:13,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:43,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/../dlib/python/pybind_utils.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/../dlib/python.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/tools/python/src/opaque_types.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/tools/python/src/dlib.cpp:4:
      /usr/include/python3.10/ceval.h:122:37: note: declared here
        122 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(void) PyEval_InitThreads(void);
            |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      [ 71%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/src/matrix.cpp.o
      In file included from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:16,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/attr.h:13,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:43,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/../dlib/python/pybind_utils.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/../dlib/python.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/tools/python/src/opaque_types.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/tools/python/src/matrix.cpp:4:
      /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/internals.h: In function ‘pybind11::detail::internals& pybind11::detail::get_internals()’:
      /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/internals.h:194:27: warning: ‘void PyEval_InitThreads()’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        194 |         PyEval_InitThreads();
            |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:130,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:112,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pytypes.h:12,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:13,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/attr.h:13,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:43,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/../dlib/python/pybind_utils.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/../dlib/python.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/tools/python/src/opaque_types.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/tools/python/src/matrix.cpp:4:
      /usr/include/python3.10/ceval.h:122:37: note: declared here
        122 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(void) PyEval_InitThreads(void);
            |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      [ 72%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/src/vector.cpp.o
      In file included from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:16,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/attr.h:13,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:43,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/../dlib/python/pybind_utils.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/../dlib/python.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/tools/python/src/opaque_types.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/tools/python/src/vector.cpp:4:
      /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/internals.h: In function ‘pybind11::detail::internals& pybind11::detail::get_internals()’:
      /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/internals.h:194:27: warning: ‘void PyEval_InitThreads()’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        194 |         PyEval_InitThreads();
            |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:130,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:112,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pytypes.h:12,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:13,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/attr.h:13,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:43,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/../dlib/python/pybind_utils.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/dlib/../dlib/python.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/tools/python/src/opaque_types.h:6,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/tools/python/src/vector.cpp:4:
      /usr/include/python3.10/ceval.h:122:37: note: declared here
        122 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(void) PyEval_InitThreads(void);
            |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
      compilation terminated.
      gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/build.make:104: CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/src/vector.cpp.o] Error 1
      gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:118: CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/all] Error 2
      gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/setup.py", line 222, in <module>
          setup(
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/setup.py", line 134, in run
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-88jz6z10/dlib_645016c7ef8843149dbaaf156d8387b7/setup.py", line 174, in build_extension
 subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '-j1']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... \^canceled
ERROR: Operation cancelled by user
```

Comment: Do you have enough memory?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method

```
cd ~  
git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git dlib
cd  dlib/
python3 setup.py install
```